# How to handle user certificate while accessing from selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, ssl-certificate

Currently while opening the browser by selenium, it not asking the user certificate popup and directly navigated to the access denied page since none of the certificate get selected. How we can handle it from code ?

Comment: Can you consider showing your work with us please? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, What I understand from question that you are getting an untrusted certificate while launching the browser which needs to be handled. For that you can browser profile and can set accept to all untrusted certificates. Some thing like below:

```
FirefoxProfile profile=new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver(profile);
driver.get("url");
```

For Chrome, you can use DesiredCapabilities.

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();      
caps.setCapability (CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true)
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(caps);
```